# How to get the correct array in multiple - dimension array

Tags: python, machine-learning

Python programming:
x_train.shape is (60000,28,28,1)
How I can convert my data to (60000,28,28)
When I type x_train[0] , it can show a 28 x 28 array.

Comment: use `numpy.squeeze`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.squeeze()` to remove single single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.

```py
np.squeeze(x_train)
```

[Link to documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)